# Provide a card that has the 'currency' field set when adding a card to a Stripe account

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, stripe-payments

I'm using CardElement in React native and I'm getting this error back when creating a Debit card token.

Error:

> You must provide a card that has the 'currency' field set when adding
> a card to a Stripe account

My code to create the token:

```
const stripe = useStripe();
const elements = useElements();

const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    // Block native form submission.
    // event.preventDefault();
    if (!stripe || !elements) {
        // Stripe.js has not loaded yet. Make sure to disable
        // form submission until Stripe.js has loaded.
        return;
    }
    // Get a reference to a mounted CardElement. Elements knows how
    // to find your CardElement because there can only ever be one of
    // each type of element.

    const cardElement = elements.getElement(CardElement);

    // Use your card Element with other Stripe.js APIs
    stripe.createToken(cardElement).then(function (result) {
        // Handle result.error or result.token
        const cardId = result.token.card.id
        console.log("TOKEN: ", result.token)
        const token = result.token.id
        // Send token and id to firebase 
        ref.doc('spE8oRHDBChYPTVgF8BayBTJKmP2').collection('external_accounts').doc(cardId).set({
            token: token,
        });
    });
};
```

How do I add the currency field when using Elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide an optional data object as the second argument to `stripe.createToken` that contains the `currency`, like this:

```
stripe.createToken(cardElement, { 'currency': 'usd' }).then(function (result) {
```

Documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/js/tokens_sources/create_token?type=cardElement#stripe_create_token-data-currency